# PHP - putting a variable, with a string containing the URL coding, into a URL

Tags: php, variables, url

Is there a way to put the coding that would normally go in a (PHP) url into a variable string, and then put that variable string into the URL. The code below doesn't work. Any advice?

```
$FirstName = "Jane";
$LastName = "Doe";

$url = "'&firstName='.$FirstName";
$url .= "'&lastName='.$LastName";

<a href="test2.php?occupation=<?php echo $Occupation; ?><?php echo $URL; ?>">Click</a>
```

Comment: Did you try &firstname without Any quotes around them?

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php

Comment: I have tried with and without quotes, and switched the single and double quotes around, to no avail!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've concatenated `$FirstName` and `$LastName` to the URL, why not add in `$Occupation`. And to make the whole thing neat and clean, add in to the `$url` `test2.php`.

```
$FirstName  = "Jane" ;
$LastName   = "Doe"  ;

$url  = "test2.php?" ;
$url .= "occupation=$Occupation" ;
$url .= "&firstName=$FirstName" ;
$url .= "&lastName=$LastName" ;
```

Then print the whole URL to the `href` attribute.

```
<a href="<?php echo $url; ?>">Click</a>
```

Comment: This code looks perfect! However when I click on the link, it does NOT direct me to test2.php. <a href="">click</a> is how the source code appears.

Comment: You tried to use the code i've given and it results to an empty href attribute?

Comment: Try echoing the whole thing like **echo "<a href='$url'>Click</a>" ;**

Comment: My bad! It was a typo on my part that was causing the issue. You're coding was perfect! Thanks man!

Answer (score 0):

Close PHP with `?>` before directly displaying HTML in your script file

```
?><a href="test2.php?occupation=<?php echo $Occupation; ?><?php echo $URL; ?>">Click</a>
```

Comment: Then explain what you mean by "doesn't work".... does it display anything (even if you have to do a "view source" to see it)? does it return an error? does it kick the cat? does it display the wrong thing? Does Jane run?

Comment: When you click on the link, it takes you to the page test2.php, but the variables (firstName & lastName) are not displayed on test2.php. The do appear when a normal HTML URL is used: <a href="test2.php?occupation=<?php echo $Occupation; ?>&firstName=<?php echo $FirstName; ?>&lastName=<?php echo $LastName; ?>">Click</a>

Comment: So are you actually switching into PHP with `<?PHP` before defining the variables?